# Symfony 1.4: Print out individual checkboxes

Tags: symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I have the following form element, it generates a checkbox:

```
 $deliveryLocationChoices    = array( '0' => 'Select if Applicable',
                                       'front'    => 'Front',
                                       'rear'     => 'Rear',
                                       'left'     => 'Left Side',
                                       'right'    => 'Right Side');

 $this->setWidgets(array(
      'delivery_location'   => new sfWidgetFormChoice(array('choices' => $deliveryLocationChoices  )),
 ));
```

It works, great, except I would like to print each individual checkbox item.  Reason being is I need to customize positioning of each box.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the way checkboxes are going to be displayed by passing a renderer_options argument to your new sfWidgetFormChoice.

That would look something like this

```
$this->setWidgets(array(
  'delivery_location'   => new sfWidgetFormChoice(array('choices' => $deliveryLocationChoices, 'renderer_options' => array('formatter' => array($this, 'checkboxFormatter')))),
));
```

Then, within your form class, define the function 'checkboxFormatter' like this

```
public static function checkboxFormatter($widget, $inputs) {}
```

That way you'll be able to access your checkboxes through the $inputs var. You must return the displaying result at the end of the checkboxFormatter function.